# Increasing the double precision values

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I am now running a program for a certain iterations. The time step is 0.01. I want to write some information when a specific time is reached. For example:

```
  program abc
  implicit none
  double precision :: time,step,target
  integer :: x

  time = 0.d0
  step = 0.01
  target = 5.d0

  do x = 1,6000
     time = time + step
     "some equations here to calculate the model parameters"
     if(time.eq.target)then
        write(*,*) "model parameters"
      endif
   enddo
```

However, "time" never equals to 1.0 or 2.0 or etc. It shows like "0.999999866" instead of "1.0" and "1.99999845" instead of "2.0".

Although I can use integer "x" to define when to write the information, I prefer to use the time step. Also, I may want to change the time step (0.01/0.02/0.05/etc) or target (5.0/6.0/8.0/etc).

Does anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks ahead.

Comment: `if(x.eq.nint(target/step))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have now discovered floating point arithmetic! Just ensure that the time is sufficiently close to the target.

`if(abs(time-target) < 0.5d0*step ) then
...`

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic is not perfect and your variables are always exact up to a certain machine error, depending on your variables' number format (32, 64, 128 bit). The following example illustrates well this characteristic:

```
PROGRAM main 
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, qp => real128
    IMPLICIT NONE 

    REAL(qp) :: a, b, c 

    a = 128._qp      
    b = a/120._qp + 1  
    c = 120._qp*(b-1)  

    PRINT*, "a = ", a
    PRINT*, "c = ", c  
END PROGRAM main
```

Here is the output to this program with `gfortran v.4.6.3`:

```
 a =    128.00000000000000000      
 c =    127.99999999999999999
```